# YouTube API Ignoring Autoplay Flag

Tags: youtube-api

I'm embedding an iframe with the following src:

```
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/2NUdEvBliD4?autoplay=1&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;rel=0&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;version=3&amp;playerapiid=mbYTP_youtube1&amp;origin=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8888&amp;allowfullscreen=true&amp;wmode=transparent&amp;iv_load_policy=3&amp;html5=1"
```

The video loads only the cover image, but does not begin playing. It's the only one of the flags it seems to ignore.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean :

```
  <iframe frameborder="0" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/2NUdEvBliD4?autoplay=1&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;rel=0&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;version=3&amp;playerapiid=mbYTP_youtube1&amp;origin=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8888&amp;allowfullscreen=true&amp;wmode=transparent&amp;iv_load_policy=3&amp;html5=1"></iframe>
```

**[LIVE EXAMPLE](http://jsbin.com/cocatuta/24/)**

Comment: Yeah, seems to work on a standalone player, but in the full site, it's being ignored: http://wptrunk.notne.com/

Comment: Found an issue with mb.YT.Player throwing a js error. Thanks anyway!

Comment: of course, if you don't share all your code, how can we help you. despairing